# Informatica PowerCenter Performance with DD 7.1 PostgreSQL Driver

Tags: postgresql, odbc, informatica

I am using PowerCenter 10.4.1 with the DataDirect 7.1 PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver to write to tables in a PostgreSQL 14 database. The write performance is poor compared to writing to Oracle 12 using native Oracle drivers. I did some testing of this and Oracle is about 35 times faster writing than Postgres with the DD driver. I have tried the different values for the ODBC driver BatchMechanism property. It did make a difference with the value = 2, but even with that the best I can get with Postgres is 35 times slower than Oracle. Read performance with PC and this driver many times better than Oracle, so I don't understand why write performance is so much worse. Both the Oracle and the Postgres table are identical in terms of columns, indexes, constraints, etc.

I did the same test recreating my test mapping entirely in PL/SQL in Postgres and the write performance is as good, or better than, Oracle. So I am confident it is not a problem with the Postgres database.

Informatica support will not answer questions on Postgres. I have opened a case, and the response is 'Informatica does not support PosgreSQL with ODBC. Purchase the PowerExchange for PostgreSQL connector'. The funny thing about that last statement is Informatica no longer sells licenses for the PowerExchange connector, so that is not an option (and that information came directly from their licensing people). They want people to purchase IICS for Postgres support.

So my question is, has anyone been able to get good write performance in PowerCenter with the DataDirect 7.1 PostgreSQL driver? What is the problem that causes the write performance to be so bad? Would it be any better with DataDirect 8 or is write performance with ODBC just poor in general for any database?

Comment: I >guess< that with DD this is a Normal load, not a Bulk load. Please verify. Next, check if you've got indexes that could be removed befor the load and recreated after. And verify the commit interval (make sure it's high). Let me know the throughput in rows and the total number of rows being loaded.

Comment: Correct, it is a 'Normal' load. There is not even an option, at least from the Informatica session to set to 'Bulk', when using ODBC. The table I am loading for the test has no indexes or constraints, and commit interval is 10k. Oracle write throughput in rows/sec: 160k. Postgres write throughput in rows/sec: 5k

Comment: Can you confirm if Oracle has been loaded with bulk option? If so, I guess that's it. This is the advantage of using dedicated connector and bulk option over ODBC with Normal load.

Comment: The Oracle test was done as 'Normal' load, not Bulk.

Comment: Still, it's a native connector. Don't have a proof, but that's what I usually observe with ODBC/JDBC: it is way slower.